# Following Sunday based on date in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I'm looking to create a calculation to display the following Sunday in day-month format based on the current date (`=NOW()`).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Excel with

```
=TODAY() - WEEKDAY(TODAY()) + 8
```

and this is a simple enough formula that it’s probably the same in LibreOffice.  `WEEKDAY(`*`date`*`)` returns 1 if the date is Sunday, 2 if it’s Monday, …, 7 for Saturday, so *`date`*`- WEEKDAY(`*`date`*`)` computes the Saturday before *`date`*, so adding 8 gets the following Sunday.  If you’d rather use `NOW()`, just plug it in instead of `TODAY()`, but note that, if the current time is 5:42, the formula will compute 5:42 on the following Sunday. 
If you want to force it to midnight, try

```
=INT(NOW()) - WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 8
```

Use cell formatting to display it however you want.

Comment: Works perfectly in LibreOffice Calc (tested with 3.6).